# Preg_replace pattern with brackets and quotes

Tags: preg-replace

How to transform this :

```
<a href="{cms_selflink href='my-link' }">My text</a>
```

Into this :

```
<a href="/page/my-link">My text</a>
```

I've tried this :

```
$masque1 = "/\{cms_selflink href=\'(.*?)\'(.*)\}/i";
$masque2 = '/page/$1';
$texte = preg_replace($masque1, $masque2, $texte);
```

But this don't work.

Any idea plz ? Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work :

```
$masque1 = "/\{cms_selflink href=\'(.+?)\' \}/s";
```